# error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, dpkg, openstack

I'm installing openstack in Virtual Box ubuntu VDI 22.04.
I try tu run
`./stack.sh`

But i get error message :

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-34-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda4
I: (UUID=fea6d28a-87d8-4e12-90f8-127fb098d3ce)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
zstd: error 25 : Write error : No space left on device (cannot write compressed block) 
E: mkinitramfs failure zstd -q -1 -T0 25
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-34-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
+functions-common:apt_get:1                exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:545                  local r=100
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:546                  jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:546                  jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:549                  [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:555                  '[' -f '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:560                  kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:455               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:562                  [[ 100 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:563                  echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:565                  type -p generate-subunit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:568                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:571                  /usr/bin/python3.10 /opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2023-10-11-180629.txt for details
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:580                  exit 100
```

Does this mean I have to add storage capacity to the virtual box? Or is there something else missing?

Answer (score 2):

The error is, `zstd: error 25 : Write error : No space left on device (cannot write compressed block)` , which means, your Ubuntu installation ran out of space.

If you install a lot of programs, you need at least 60 GB or so for the root partition of Ubuntu (irrespective of whether it is a virtual machine or not). You now have two options.

---

1. You can [enlarge](https://itsfoss.com/increase-disk-size-virtualbox/) the virtualbox disk. This will involve enlarging the disk, and then enlarging the root partition within the disk using a GParted live image.
2. If you don't want to go through all that hassle, then reinstall Ubuntu in another virtual machine, and ensure to set at least 60-70 GB disk space.